# external Superdrive from a MBP does not work correctly

Tags: optical-drive

I have replaced the Superdrive in my 2012 MBP 13" with a second hard drive. The Superdrive  is now in a external USB case. I have no problems by using the drive with data disc, like games or music disc, but I can’t play video DVDs via the DVD Player app, I always get a error message. Worse I can not rip DVDs via Ripit.app, because also with this app, I get error.

The Superdrive seems not the problem, because attached to my 2012 mini without an internal drive, it works just fine.

Can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you play DVDs with VLC?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which external USB case is it?